# Diminished receptivity of paper to pencil during periods of humidity

Tags: humidity, adhesion

Why does paper become less receptive to pencil when it is humid out? I have generally experienced this with a 4B pencil.

Comment: Paper fibers absorb water and swell becoming softer and less able to rub off graphite particles from the pencil?

Answer (score 0):

Continuing Martin Beckett's argument (see comment above), the softness of the fibres reduces the friction between the graphite and the paper. With less friction there is a smaller shearing stress on the graphite, so the layers of carbon atoms don't slide over each other as readily, so not as much graphite is deposited on the paper.